# from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protos'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement the code for number plate detection. I am working with tensorflow 2.1. The code i was working on was compatible with tensorflow 1.x, i made the necessary changes. But the following piece of code gives trouble:

```
import logging

import tensorflow as tf

from google.protobuf import text_format
from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

...

The following error comes:

```
File "C:/Users/hp/Downloads/Compressed/models1/utils/label_map_util.py", line 24, in <module>
    from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protos'
```

I have tried all the implementations that are available on internet but it is not working. Can anyone guide me what is the way forward? Thanks.

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format code & error messages (done it for you this time).

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut i will be careful next time.

Comment: How did you install the package protos? I could not find any package with that name

Comment: That is the thing i am unable to understand. I installed protobuf package from anaconda but still unable to run it. Also in the project there is file named protos in which string_int_label_map_pb2 is placed @neelg

Comment: Could you post your whole code in a self-contained Colab notebook so that we can better understand the problem you have?

Comment: @neelg how do i do it i.e.post the whole code. Can you please guide as i am a newbie here? I would be great full for your patience. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/georgi-valkov/Deep-Learning-License-Plate-Recognition/tree/7654f0dd2081ab4b35f9e82e3b58553f7d6ba0be

Comment: This is the link of the code I am trying to implement. In this i am more concerned with detect.py file.@neelg

Comment: Sure. just look up "colab" in your search engine. Go to their website and sign-in with your E-mail. Colab is basically a place where you can run your code with free GPU. It already has most popular libraries preinstalled So you have to do minimal work. Setting up your code in colab is really helpful to us. If you have any queries, look it up. There are plenty of resources for working in COlab...

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_R9ZFmGba4smcnOqDp445RUF7ZbNQgFK#scrollTo=rWvOCjWTj_wE&uniqifier=1 . Here is the main code and the part of the code giving error @neelg. Thanks for guiding.

Answer (score -1):

i solve this problem by coping the file in protos folder in the folder where string_int_label_map_pb2 is to enable import